# ASP.NET Identity OAuth2 and Limited Input Devices

Tags: c#, .net, swift, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I need to use the OAuth infrastructure to log in limited input devices like Apple Watch with ASP.NET Identity and OAuth 2.

The iOS app and the ASP.NET Web App work fine together but I can't find any example about Apple Watch and the digit code.

I'd like the Youtube/Netflix interface with a 4 digit code to input in another logged device but I don't know where to start. The Google documentation refers to it but it only explain the process, no code there.

I'm using `ASP.NET Identity` for OAuth server implementation and `OAuthSwift` for iOS/watchOS code but the documentation is really poor for the two frameworks.

Somebody already found a solution for this problem or has some examples to study?

Comment: Read up on `oauth2 device flow`. Sadly the specification is still a draft as far as I know. But [here](https://alexbilbie.com/2016/04/oauth-2-device-flow-grant/) is a good overview.